# How to run a paraview Python code using pvbatch or pv python

Tags: python, paraview

I am trying to run this Python file using `pvpython [filename].py`

```
from paraview.simple import *
servermanager.Connect()
#sphere = Sphere();
#Show();

import os
i = 0
SubDir = [" "]*30
# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '/var/www/html/php/emd/job552e23fe74d102/VTK'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if dirName == rootDir + '/others':
       continue
    if dirName == rootDir:
       continue
    SubDir.append(dirName)
    i=i+1
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        j=1
        j= LegacyVTKReader( FileNames=[dirName + '/' + fname] )
```

and I am getting this error

```
File "paraview.py", line 2, in <module>
    from paraview.simple import *
File "/var/www/html/php/emd/job552e23fe74d102/VTK/paraview.py", line 2, in <module>
    from paraview.simple import *
ImportError: No module named simple
```

Is there anywhere I have gone wrong. Please help me, I am a beginner in this.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. I tried to run it inside Paraview Python shell, and it seems to work. On the other hand, this question seems to be off-topic for me, since it is more related to you particular code and not with Computational Science.

Comment: I agree with nicoguaro.  This question is better fit for the Stack Overflow site, since it deals more with debugging.

Comment: have you downloaded pvpython as a pre-built binary or have you built it yourself? Are you able to import paraview.simple in the paraview gui python shell? have you maybe moved installation files or folders?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me if I do not add the directory that holds the ParaView Libraries to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH system variable. I have ParaView 4.0.1 installed as an example and I append the path to the variable as follows in Ubuntu:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/sgeadmin/ParaView-4.0.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.0