# How to run application specific python commands on IDLE?

Tags: python-2.7, paraview

I just want to know if it is possible to run python commands on IDLE for a software called 'Paraview', which has an inbuilt python shell to run specific commands to perform certain tasks like creating a cone,  for example:

```
cone = Cone()
```

Creates a cone in the software. I tried importing the required modules on IDLE but got this error:
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U6bY.png)

However when I run the same code on paraview's python shell there's no error. I tried changing PYTHONPATH to the module location and also tried copying the modules in the default PYTHONPATH location, but I still get the same error. I want to know why I'm getting this error and if it's possible to run application specific commands on IDLE. I'm sorry for any formatting inconvenience as I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: Could you put the import error message in plain text in order to improve the readability of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your issue is related to this one: [How to run a paraview Python code using pvbatch or pv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923266/how-to-run-a-paraview-python-code-using-pvbatch-or-pv-python/30635639#30635639), yet with a rather old version of Paraview.

So you should also update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and add the location of the Paraview and VTK dynamic libraries accordingly to your Paraview installation path and version.